# Simple present vs. deterministic future

Tags: verbs, present-continuous, present-simple, future-time

When I record a video in which I demonstrate a software application in action, I should say `I click on the button` or `I am clicking on the button`?

In the video, I click on the button one second after saying the sentence. They can use the application in the way in which I have shown them in anytime.

Comment: @   any. Do you want present activity or  future activity?

Comment: @Englishmonger One second later activity. I am showing them that I click on the button. They can use the application in the way in which I have shown them in anytime.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to indicate that you click one second after saying the sentence. That will help people write you a clear and specific answer. Please double-check that this is what you want to ask.

Answer (score -1):

> **I click on the button**.
>
> **I am clicking on the button**.
>
> **I will click on the button**.

All are correct.

The simple present is frequently used even for ongoing actions in science classes and commentaries.

The present progressive is possible as it is used for activities that are happening at the time of speaking.

The simple future is possible because you might perform an action shortly after saying what you are going to do.

Comment: We can use the simple present when demonstrating a process or sequence of events: "I crack the egg; I put the yolk and white into the pan; I use the spatula to stop it sticking; I turn it over (etc)."

Comment: Please be more careful leaving answers on ELL. Your answers are often riddled with typographical errors, especially around punctuation. It is not the community's job to fix these substandard answers for you.

Comment: @  J.RPlease leave the answers unedited.They may be downvoted.  You need not correct them.

Comment: @Englishmonger - Please read the [Our Model](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/editing) entry in the Help Pages. Here is one quote from that page: _If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you._ In other words, if you don't want your posts edited, then make them exemplary. P.S. I'd rather fix a salvageable answer than downvote one for its sloppiness and leave the mediocre answer here for the world to see – particularly when it is the only answer provided.